# ASP.net ListBox currency formatting

Tags: c#, asp.net, listbox

Ok guys, I have a ListBox which displays products (they are a custom class and have ID, name, price) that are in a binding list.. I want the ListBox to display the item name AND the price. The listbox (lbProductsChosen) has "DataTextField" set to the Name and DataValueField set to the ID. I am using the PreRender event to check each Item, look at its price from the binding list (blProducts) etc. and it works great. I get the name and price displayed in the list with this. However, when it is displayed, despite me formatting it using String.Format, the result is still a decimal number (ex. 3.20000) and it just looks ugly. Does anyone know why its working to display it, but not displaying it how I want it formatted.

```
    protected void lbProductsChosen_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (ListItem item in lbProductsChosen.Items)
        {
            string currentDescription = item.Text;
            int convertedValue = Convert.ToInt32(item.Value);
            for (int i = 0; i < blProducts.Count; i++)
            {
                if (blProducts[i].ProductID == convertedValue)
                {
                    decimal ItemPrice = blProducts[i].Price;
                    string convertedPrice = ItemPrice.ToString();
                    string currentPrice = String.Format("{0:c}", convertedPrice);
                    string currentDescriptionPadded = currentDescription.PadRight(30);
                    item.Text = currentDescriptionPadded + currentPrice;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.string.format(v=vs.110).aspx#Format_Culture) states the following about the `String.Format` method.

> Generally, objects in the argument list are converted to their string representations by using the conventions of the current culture, which is returned by the CultureInfo.CurrentCulture property.

If you use the currency format specifier `c` it will use the currency format which is defined in the system settings. Take a look under `control panel` -> `region` -> `additional settings` -> `currency`. Maybe you have messed up settings there.

[image]

---

If you want to ignore the local settings which would make sense for currency you could do the following. (example in dollar with allways two decimal places)

```
decimal price = 12.10999999m;
String.Format("${0:0.00}", price);
```

> $12.10

Be aware of that `String.Format` doesn't round the number correctly but just cuts it off.

Comment: Thanks. The local settings are all right since I am using the currency conversion in other parts of my program and it works. Just cant figure out why its not formatting it here, there are no errors. I will try it with your example and hopefully it works, although it might just not register it like the format I used, since it is infact not from the local settings. Will give feedback tomorrow.